# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint error on JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have 2 tables. tablea is parent and tableb is child and associated with scode
tablea
   scode
   rcode
   sabbr
   sname
tablea : primar key : scode

tableb
  aid
  scode
  acode
  aname
tableb : primary key : aid. This is AUTO GENERATED
st_ar_UX(scode,acode)
st_ar_fk(scode)

I am using spring batch+spring data jpa to insert records into tableb only (That's my REQUIRMENT).

When the spring batch is completed, I see 3 rows inserted which are below as scode, scode, aname into tableb. But I get an errors saying

Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (st_ar_UX) violated. Why would this come and how to resolve.

01|001|AUTAUGA
01|003|BALDWIN
01|005|BARBOUR

Comment: Is scode,acode you Unique contraint in the table, it seems two rows are getting added from your code with same scode,acode values, since error came while adding in table so you will not be able to see that record in the table, check your logs for stacktrace and enable tracing to find the exact record which is giving problem

Comment: I figured out that tableb has one column which has to be joined using @JoinColumn